# Karma not running tests that have "import" statements in karma-webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, karma-webpack

I have some test files with tests I'd like to run against my app.

I am attempting to use `karma`, `karma-webpack`, `karma-babel-preprocessor`, `karma-chrome-launcher`, and `jasmine` in my testing. My app depends on many things, including `backbone`, `marionette`, etc. My app is built using `webpack`, and I am attempting to use `webpack` to bundle my files together for testing. (I initially wanted to see if I could skip this step, i.e. simply `import` a file to be tested, but it seems this is impossible.)

My test script looks like

**package.json** (scripts section)

```
"test": "./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start",
```

The rest of the files:

**karma.conf.js**

```
var webpackConfig = require('./config/webpack/webpack.test.conf.js');

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      { pattern: 'test/**/*.spec.js', watched: true },
      { pattern: 'test/*.spec.js', watched: true }
    ],
    exclude: [
    ],
    preprocessors: {
        'test/**/*.spec.js': ['webpack'],
        'test/*.spec.js': ['webpack']
    },
    webpack: webpackConfig,
    webpackMiddleware: {
        stats: 'errors-only'
    },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,    
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,           
    autoWatch: true,       
    browsers: ['Chrome'],        
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

**test/test.spec.js** This file is seen

```
describe("A suite", function () {
    it("contains spec with an expectation", function () {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
describe("Another suite", function () {
    it("contains another spec with an expectation", function () {
        expect(true).toBe(false);
    });
});
```

**test/models/devicegroup.spec.js** This file is not seen

```
import backbone from 'backbone';

describe("backbone", function () {
    it("containsasdfasdfasdfasdfspec with an expectation", function () 
  {
        expect(true).toBe(false);
    });
});
```

My folder structure is:

```
- karma.conf.js
- test/
- - test.spec.js
- - models/
- - - devicegroup.spec.js
- public/
- - js/
- - - app.js
```

When my files don't have `import` statements at the top, karma will run and pass/fail as expected. Putting an `import` statement at the top will cause karma to ignore the file. No errors are thrown.

**How can I make karma / karma-webpack run my tests that have import statements / what is the karma-safe way to import modules into my tests?**

When **test/models/devicegroup.spec.js** does not have an `import` statement:

```
// import backbone from 'backbone';

describe("backbone", function () {
    it("contains with an expectation", function () {
        expect(true).toBe(false);
    });
});
```

the terminal output is: (notice one less test is run)

[image: Screenshot of terminal output karma successfully running test of file without import statement]

When **test/models/devicegroup.spec.js** does have an `import` statement:

```
import backbone from 'backbone';

describe("backbone", function () {
    it("contains with an expectation", function () {
        expect(true).toBe(false);
    });
});
```

the terminal output is:

[image: Screenshot of terminal output of karma when not able to see files with import statements]

I see no errors in the browser Karma opens.

EDIT:

I have experimented by adding my source files to the `files` and `preprocessors` attributes in my `karma.conf.js` file, as per [this repo example](https://bitbucket.org/knee-cola/webpack-karma/src/36a86afda677?at=master). There was no change in behavior other than a massively increased testing time.

**karma.conf.js**

```
files: [
  { pattern: 'public/js/**/*.js', watched: true},
  { pattern: 'test/**/*.spec.js', watched: true },
  // each file acts as entry point for the webpack configuration
],

preprocessors: {
    // add webpack as preprocessor
    'public/js/**/*.js': ['webpack'],
    'test/**/*.spec.js': ['webpack'],
},
```

EDIT2:
For the sake of experimentation ([and based off this person's struggles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46271962/karma-webpack-jasmine-unit-testing-not-working)), I have tried the above karma.conf.js in every possible combination - only test files in `files` and `preprocessors`, only source files, test files in one but not the other, source files in one but not the other, none, both. No good results, though occasionally new errors.

Comment: Did you notice

frameworks: ['jasmine'],
      { pattern: 'test/**/*.spec.js', watched: true },
      { pattern: 'test/models/*.spec.js', watched: true }
]

is missing a square bracket (or has an extra one, not sure)?

Comment: That may be a copy/paste artifact, i'm not seeing it in my code editor... just a second though lemme look closer

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, it was a copy/paste error, the code above now reflects exactly what I have locally

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue, because I'm experiencing the same thing.

Comment: Nope, I switched to using Jest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Little late, but I ran into the same problem, and was searching for hours, why my imports prevent the test suite from being executed. karma-webpack-4.0.0-rc.2 brought the enlightenment by providing **error messages**!!

I my case a couple of modules where not found, `angular-mock`, `jquery`, `angular` and more.

**How to fix**

Put there modules into the files array in your karma.config like:

```
files = [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
  "node_modules/angular/angular.js",
  "node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js",
  { pattern: "test/**/*.ts", watched: false }
```

I hope, this helps someone.

**EDIT**

My current versions of the testing related packages:

```
"@types/jasmine": "^2.8.8",
"jasmine": "^3.2.0",
"jasmine-core": "^3.2.1",
"jasmine-reporters": "2.3.2",
"jasmine-ts": "^0.2.1",
"karma": "3.0.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
"karma-jasmine": "1.1.2",
"karma-junit-reporter": "1.2.0",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.4",
"karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
"karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
"karma-webpack": "^4.0.0-rc.2",
"typescript": "3.0.3",
"webpack": "4.17.2",
"webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "3.1.8"
```

Comment: yea, I'm kinda sorry for the delay 

Comment: Don't be! You've done your part in closing one more of the internet's nigh-infinite number of unanswered questions. https://xkcd.com/979/